# P5NCI::load_func() after perl upgrade from perl-5.14 to perl-5.26.3, showing error

Tags: perl

Below is perl code which calls `P5NCI::load_func` to load function `load_library` having signature as `int load_library(int dummy)`, hence third argument is passed as `ii` to `P5NCI::load_func`

```
        my $library_path = P5NCI::find_lib( 'ESNMP.so' );
        $library      = P5NCI::load_lib( $library_path );
        print "\nLibrary loaded";
        print "\nlibrary_path".$library_path;
        my $funcldlib = P5NCI::load_func( $library, 'load_library', 'ii');
```

This was working fine till perl-5.14, but later I used it for perl-5.26.3,
but I am getting error as below:

> Don't understand NCI signature 'ii'

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it stopped working [during the Perl 5.15 development cycle](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=P5NCI+0.31). It hasn't even [built successfully for ten years](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=77325).

Seems to be unsupported. I'd look around for an alternative if I were you.

Comment: Hi @Dave Cross, thanks for your inputs in this.
Our code which was legacy code was using this P5NCI functions mentioned above.
Do you know any thread where we can take support from P5NCI forum,support community for this issue as you are saying post perl 5.15 its broken,

Comment: @AmitM: Well, you could email the author (his email address is in the AUTHOR section of [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/P5NCI)), but I suspect he won't be able to help you - given that he seems to have lost interest in the module fifteen years ago. I think your best idea is to install an older version of Perl (using [perlbrew](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlbrew)) that you can use to run this program until you can replace it with something that is still supported.

Comment: Thanks. Well I already have perl 5.14, but one of our customer is reporting that perl-5.14 is not supported by RHEL so they requested if we can provide P5NCI with perl-5.26.3, but after I compiled everything(perl-5.26.3 source code, P5NCI), I observed P5NCI is not supported with perl-5.26.3 with above error.

Comment: Re "*I'd look around for an alternative if I were you.*", Check out [FFI::Platypus](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus)

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for your suggestion. Will check the feasibility of FFI::Platypus for replacing P5NCI if it achieves the same purpose to load a function from the shared library:{P5NCI::load_func(}
Also wanted to know are there any way in latest perl which I am using 5.26.3 where instead of using there CPAN external utils, I can directly do same.

Comment: @ikegami:  I can directly do same that means, I can directly achieve same directly from perl code without using P5NCI